# How get list of items in one column if satisfy condition in other column

Tags: mysql

I have this simple table in MySQL:

```
| virustotalscans | CREATE TABLE `virustotalscans` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `scanner` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `result` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `virustotalscans_scan_id` (`scan_id`),
  KEY `virustotalscans_scanner` (`scanner`),
  KEY `virustotalscans_result` (`result`),
  CONSTRAINT `virustotalscans_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`scan_id`) REFERENCES `virustotals` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9989 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I need get all scan_id for records where `result` one of all `scanner` is not NULL and in the same query I need get all `scanner` where value is not null with function GROUP_CONCACT.

For example I have three scan records `140`,`141` and `142` It was scanned with 12 antiviruses. I need get 2 record in this format: scan_id, scanner,

```
140 | K7GW, K7AntiVirus, Arcabit, Baidu, Cyren, Symantec, ESET-NOD32, TrendMicro-HouseCall, Avast  
141 | K7GW, K7AntiVirus, Arcabit, Baidu, Cyren, Symantec, ESET-NOD32, TrendMicro-HouseCall, Avast
```

Table:

```
| 1 |     140 | SUPERAntiSpyware     | NULL   
| 2 |     140 | TheHacker            | NULL                                                  
| 3 |     140 | K7GW                 | Exploit ( 04c560711 )                                 
| 4 |     140 | K7AntiVirus          | Exploit ( 04c560711 )                                 
| 5 |     140 | Arcabit              | Backdoor.Perl.Shellbot.B                              
| 6 |     140 | Baidu                | Perl.Backdoor.Shellbot.d                              
| 7 |     140 | Cyren                | Unix/ShellBot.AA                                      
| 8 |     140 | Symantec             | Perl.Santy                                            
| 9 |     140 | ESET-NOD32           | Perl/Shellbot.NAL.Gen                                 
| 10 |     140 | TrendMicro-HouseCall | PERL_SHELLBOT.SM                                      
| 11 |     140 | Avast                | Perl:Bot-A [Trj]                                      
| 12 |     140 | ClamAV               | NULL                                                  
| 13 |     141 | SUPERAntiSpyware     | NULL                                                  
| 14 |     141 | TheHacker            | NULL                                                  
| 15 |     141 | K7GW                 | Malware                                 
| 16 |     141 | K7AntiVirus          | Exploit ( 04c560811 )                                 
| 17 |     141 | Arcabit              | Backdoor                             
| 18 |     141 | Baidu                | Perl.Backdoor                             
| 19 |     141 | Cyren                | Unix/ShellBot.BB                                      
| 20 |     141 | Symantec             | Perl.Santy.B                                            
| 21 |     141 | ESET-NOD32           | Perl/Shellbot.NAL.A                                 
| 22 |     141 | TrendMicro-HouseCall | PERL_SHELLBOT.CM                                     
| 23 |     141 | Avast                | Perl:Bot-C [Trj]                                      
| 24 |     141 | ClamAV               | NULL                                                  
| 25 |     142 | SUPERAntiSpyware     | NULL                                                  
| 26 |     142 | TheHacker            | NULL                                                  
| 27 |     142 | K7GW                 | NULL                                 
| 28 |     142 | K7AntiVirus          | NULL                                 
| 29 |     142 | Arcabit              | NULL                             
| 30 |     142 | Baidu                | NULL                             
| 31 |     142 | Cyren                | NULL                                   
| 32 |     142 | Symantec             | NULL                                            
| 33 |     142 | ESET-NOD32           | NULL                                 
| 34 |     142 | TrendMicro-HouseCall | NULL                                     
| 35 |     142 | Avast                | NULL                                      
| 36 |     142 | ClamAV               | NULL
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Probably easiest to do the GROUP_CONCAT in a sub-select, and the filter for is not null in the outer select

Comment: @Lennart can you post any example please?

Comment: Look at Rick James solution. As a general advice, just don't copy the solution, try to understand how it works. That will answer your question in the comment to his solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  scan_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(scanner ORDER BY scanner)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE scan_id IN (140,141,142)
      AND result IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY scan_id
```

No subquery is needed.
The `ORDER BY scanner` is optional; use it if you want the list alphabetized.
Leave off `AND result IS NOT NULL` if you don't care if `result` is `NULL`.

You mentioned "12"; if it is critical to the query, please explain.

Comment: thanks, items 140, 141 and 142 are only for example, real table has many "scan_id" items. Number 12 is the same only for example, it is "scanner" item, these examples "scan_id" were scaned with 12 antiviruses ("scanner"). In real use one "scan_id" has about 67 asociated antivirus scans ("scanner").

Comment: So can you help me please with universal solution, not only for concrete items 140,141,142 please?

Comment: @user41060 - The `IN` clause I mentioned is somewhat 'universal'.  Or do you have a different case?